# Center an image in a React Native component

Tags: react-native

I have started playing with React Native and I'm trying to create a simple image button component just to get used to the language.
Here is what I have:

```
'use strict';

const React = require('React');
const PropTypes = require('prop-types');

import {
    Platform, TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet, Dimensions,
    Text, Image,
    View
  } from 'react-native';
const TouchableNativeFeedback = require('TouchableNativeFeedback');


const MyBrown = '#89664C';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: Platform.select({
        ios: {
        },
        android: {
            elevation: 4,
            backgroundColor: MyBrown,
            borderRadius: 2
        }
    }),
    text: Platform.select({
        ios: {
            color: 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            padding: 8,
            fontSize: 18
        },
        android: {
            color: 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            padding: 8,
            fontWeight: '500',
        }
    }),
    icon: {
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
    }
});

export default class MyButton extends React.Component{

    render(){            
        return(
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <TouchableOpacity>                    
                    <Image source={this.props.src} style={styles.icon} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            )
    }
}
```

This renders as I'd expect when I run the app, but the image is left aligned whilst the text is centered.
Now I thought I could use Flexbox and add **{flex:1}** to the parent View or TouchOpacity elements, but as soon as I do this the control no longer renders in my app.

Two questions on this:

1. What is the recommended way of centering the image in React
   Native?
2. Why, when I add the flex:1 to ether of the parent
   controls does it no longer render at all?

Thank you

Comment: Can you pls provide the button's screenshot and the whole screen also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the best way to center image is to wrap it with parent view and add flex styles to it and there is no need to pass `flex: 1`

```
> justifyContent: 'center',
> alignItems: 'center',
```

2. Prefered way to take care of image size is width and height, flex: 1 you should use for background images etc

Comment: So if I add those to styles.button, it has no impact on the layout. Does it need to be on the root view (in the original post) or the TouchableOpacity element?

Comment: i would recommend to add `View` inside `TouchableOpacity`, and pass style to that view

Comment: Thanks, @WojtekSzafraniec your comment was really helpful.

Comment: Could you add the code you used to get this to work?  I tried following the advice in your answer and comment, but to no avail.